# I keep getting three errors when trying to define a character array

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Errors**

> Instance variable is already declared
>
> Type name requires a specifier or a qualifier
>
> Expected ';' at end of declaration list

I can't figure out why this is happening. Please help!

*Here is my code*:

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "evalViewController.h"

@interface evalViewController () {
    digits[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}; //Errors: Instance variable is already declared, Type name requires a specifier or a qualifier, Expected ';' at end of declaration list 

    }

@end

@implementation evalViewController 

@synthesize terminal;
@synthesize expression; 

//Add iEval prefix to output
-(void)writeToTerminal:(NSString *)string {
    self.terminal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ConsoleCalc> %@", string];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Define operation characters
    self.add = '+';
    self.sub = '-';
    self.mult = '*';
    self.div = '/';

    //Define digits to compare to digits in editableExpression 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)evaluate:(UITextField *)sender {
    //Set user input to NSString editableExpression
    NSString *editableExpression = self.expression.text;

    //Loop through new NSString
    for (int i=0; i < editableExpression.length; i++ ){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        //Check if there is a + sign anywhere in the expression and write "Addition!" if there is
        if (charAtPosition == self.add){
            if ([self checkForDigits]){
                 [self writeToTerminal:@"There are digits in this string!"];
            }
            else {
                 [self writeToTerminal:@"There are no digits in this string!"];
             }
                    
         }
         //Check if there is a - sign anywhere in the expression and write "Subtraction!" if there is
        else if (charAtPosition == self.sub) {
             [self writeToTerminal:@"Subtraction!"];
        
         }
    
        //Check if there is a * sign anywhere in the expression and write "Multiplication!" if there is
        else if (charAtPosition == self.mult) {
             [self writeToTerminal:@"Multiplication!"];
        }
    
        //Check if there is a / sign anywhere in the expression and write "Division!" if there is
        else if (charAtPosition == self.div) {
            [self writeToTerminal: @"Division!"];
        }

    }

 }

//clear the terminal

- (IBAction)clearTerminal:(id)sender {
     [self writeToTerminal:@""];
 }

- (BOOL)checkForDigits {
    NSString *editableExpression = self.expression.text;
    for (int i = 0; i < editableExpression.length; i++){
        char charAtPosition = [editableExpression characterAtIndex:i];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++ ){
            if (charAtPosition == digits[c]){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    


    }
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface evalViewController : UIViewController {
     char digits[10];

 }

//Large text view
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *terminal;

//User input
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *expression;

//Evaluate expression
- (IBAction)evaluate:(UITextField *)sender;

- (IBAction)clearTerminal:(id)sender;

//Operation characters
@property char add;
@property char sub;
@property char mult;
@property char div;

//Change to information view
 - (void)writeToTerminal: (NSString *) string;
 - (BOOL)checkForDigits;




@end
```

Comment: While I don't know Objective-C, you seem to define `digits` in the header file, and then re-define it in the source file.

Comment: Line number where the errors occur would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the array incorrectly. Delete it from the header completely, and declare the `digits` char array only in the implementation file (.m file). The error should then go away. Also, you are assigning the value incorrectly. You are creating a char array of 10 elements, then you are *assigning another char array to the element at the 10th index, which doesn't exist anyway`. There are multiple errors there. It should be`digits = {...}`not`digits[10] = {...}`.

If I were you I would first start learning plain C and get the basics before moving into Objective-C, as it would only complicate more. I see that you want to create iOS apps, but to make that process easier, you first need to know the basics of C well.

Comment: Thanks, but it still says "Expected ';' at end of declaration list' where I put the digits = {...}

Comment: @blockaj could you please update the question to the latest version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

My wording might be wrong here but you are initialising digits in your interface. Do this.

You can do this in your .m file (and no need for the @interface evalViewController() @end just showing you where to put it)

```
char digits[10] = { ... };

@interface evalViewController ()

@end
```